# Foreign Key is not Updating with the primary key of other table

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I added a primary key named "loc_id" in location_table. And in employee_table, I am making 'loc_id' as foreign key. I am doing it in WAMP with "innoDB" set in both the tables and ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE is also set.

I am inserting a value in "loc_id" column of location table but the value I am inserting is not reflecting in employee table even-though it is set as foreign key in employee_table.

Example :

I am inserting a value "101" as primary key in "loc_id" column of location_table, now I think that since I have made "loc_id" column as foreign key with ON UPDATE CASCADE ON in employee_table, value should automatically reflects/show in loc_id column of employee_table.

Can anyone help me in this??

Comment: Are you inserting with some query or directly with PHPmyadmin? If you defined a foreign key doesn't mean that insert value automatically in secondary table. read document for detail http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Please post an example of what you are trying to do, what your output is, and what your *intended* output is. It appears that there may be a disconnect in your understanding of foreign keys, or just the way that this is being explained.

Comment: I used PHP for query, and also tried using PHPmyadmin but same problem. "loc_id" in employee_table is NULL even- though the corresponding primary key "loc_id" in location_table has value.

Comment: I am inserting a value "101" as primary key in "loc_id" column of location_table, now I think that since I have made "loc_id" column as foreign key with ON UPDATE CASCADE ON  in emp_table, value should automatically reflects/show in loc_id column of emp_table.

Comment: @sandeepsure Then how to get those values in secondary/child table.

Comment: @SACHING. You need to insert/update loc_id as 101 in another table with another query. Foreign key on only checks that value you are inserting/updating is existing in primary column or  not. It will not update/insert a value in secondary table column

Comment: @sandeepsure. How do we know what value "loc_id" is getting as it is a primary key and added as auto-increment on. What logic is needed to get the same id in employee_table so that both tables can be linked.

Comment: Please follow this link http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/

Comment: @sandeepsure It does not give the solution of my problem...I want to fill the loc_id column(foreign key) of employee_table with the same value as the loc_id column(primary key) of location_table o that I can know that a particular employee lives at particular location.

Comment: Show us the schema for the 2 tables in question. Also show the PHP code you are using to INSERT/UPDATE this data.